# conditionally call a function in angular from html

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements

In my chat application I want to call a audio play function from html, which will play only when user received msg from another users.

`<div ng-bind-html="m.msg">
</div>`

So, what I'm trying is whenever value came from this 'm.msg', I want call a function which will play sound in background.

Comment: Suggest you use a property of `m` that isn't html to do whatever it is you need to do. Question is just far too broad, with next to no information given, for anyone to offer real assistance. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use angularjs watch.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('parentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.m = {
      msg: ""
    };

  // Watch the msg. 
    $scope.$watch("m.msg", function(newVal, oldVal) {
     //In case it change call playAudio function
      if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    playAudio();
      }
    });
    
    function playAudio(){
     alert("Set Code for Play Audio here");
    }
  });
```

```css
.msg-wim{
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="m.msg" placeholder="Type Text...">
    
    <hr>
    
    <h1>For each char u type in the textbox alert will display</h1>
    <div class="msg-wim" ng-bind="m.msg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```